# Run OHS for Weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic

I am using weblogic12.1.3

I was install the WebLogic cluster in the above format :

cluster name : cs1, cluster address 172.30.35.23:7003,172.30.35.23:7004

I have 2 manageserver : 172.30.35.23:7003,172.30.35.23:7004

and a Machine MCH1(added 2 manage server to this machine)

my console address is : 172.30.35.23:7001/console

I have installe OHS on the other server : IP:172.30.35.13 port:7777

===============================================================

My configuration in OHS (mod_wl_ohs.conf) is :

```
LoadModule weblogic_module /u01/app/product/fmw/ohs/mosules/mod_wl_ohs.so

<IfModule weblogic_module>
        <Location /console>
        WLSRequest On
        WebLogicHost 172.30.35.23
        WeblogicPort 7001
        </Location>
</IfModule>
<IfModule weblogic_module>
        <Location /Hello>
        WLSRequest On
        WebLogicCluster 172.30.35.23:7003,172.30.35.23:7004
        </Location>
</IfModule>
```

=============================================================

my /etc/hosts on weblogic server is : 
127:0.0.1 localhost.localdomain 
172.30.35.23 weblogic2 weblogic2.localdomain

my /etc/hosts on OHS server is : 
127:0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
172.30.35.13 OHS OHS.localdomain

==============================================================
I deployed Hello.war to cluster

My test result :

```
                 172.30.35.23:70001/console   is ok
                 172.30.35.13:7777/console    is ok
                 172.30.35.23:7003/Hello      is ok
                 172.30.35.23:7004/Hello      is ok
```

but i dont have any answer on 172.30.35.13:7777/Hello
why ?
It means OHS is not working with cluster ?

ohs1.log is :

```
[oracle@OHS logs]$ cat ohs1.log 
[2015-10-05T18:21:50.6939+03:30] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [OHS-9999] [mod_weblogic.c] [client_id: 172.30.35.200] [host_id: OHS] [host_addr: 172.30.35.13] [tid: 140599950821120] [user: oracle] [ecid: 0058LmbHfxLDg^wawDedMG0005rH000006] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: main]  <0058LmbHfxLDg^wawDedMG0005rH000006> weblogic: parseServerList: 172.30.35.23:7102 apr_socket_connect error [111] Connection refused

[2015-10-05T18:21:50.6971+03:30] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [OHS-9999] [mod_weblogic.c] [client_id: 172.30.35.200] [host_id: OHS] [host_addr: 172.30.35.13] [tid: 140599950821120] [user: oracle] [ecid: 0058LmbHfxLDg^wawDedMG0005rH000006] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: main]  <0058LmbHfxLDg^wawDedMG0005rH000006> weblogic: parseJVMID: could not resolve hostname '-1407311080'. Returning NULL from parseJVMID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make WebLogic Server to accept OHS request

If the version of the Oracle WebLogic Server instances in the back end is 10.3.4 (or later releases), you must set the WebLogic Plug-In Enabled parameter.

1.
Log in to the Oracle WebLogic Server administration console.
The WebLogic Proxy Plug-In provides features that are 
identical to those of the plug-in for Apache HTTP Server.

2.
In the Domain Structure pane, expand the 
Environment node.
– If the server instances to which you want to proxy requests from Oracle 
HTTP Server are in a cluster, select Clusters.
– Otherwise, select Servers.

3.
Select the server or cluster to which you want to proxy requests from Oracle 
HTTP Server.
The Configuration: General tab is displayed.

4.
Scroll down to the Advanced section, expand it, and select the 
WebLogic Plug-In Enabled checkbox. Or change value from default to **yes** if there isn't checkbox

5.
Click Save.

6.
If you selected Servers in step 2, repeat steps 3 and 4 for the other servers to which you want to proxy requests from Oracle HTTP Servers.

For the change to take effect, you must restart the server instances.